# TLS handshake timeout on requesting data concurrently from api

Tags: go, concurrency

This is my first program in which I have used concurrency so I might be missing something fairly simple.

```
package main

import(
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "log"
    "flag"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "strings"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
    "html/template"
)

type fileInfo struct{
    Title string `json:"Title"`;
    Year string `json:"Year"`;
    Runtime string `json:"Runtime"`
    Genre string `json:"Genre"` 
    Rating string `json:"imdbRating"`;
    Description string `json:"Plot"`;
    Image string `json:"Poster"`;
    Awards string `json:"Awards"`;
}

var movie struct{
    Name string;
    Year string;
}
var Movies []fileInfo
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(flag.Args()[0])
    var queryNames []string
    for _, f := range files {
        go func(){
            queryNames= append(queryNames,url.QueryEscape(f.Name()))
        }()
    }
    //fmt.Println(os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "/src/github.com/krashcan/review/template/index.tpl")
    fmt.Println("Preparing data")


    for _, f := range queryNames {
        go GetTitleAndYear("https://opensubtitles.co/search?q=" + f)
    }




    fmt.Println("Done")
    http.HandleFunc("/",ShowRatings)
    http.Handle("/static/",http.StripPrefix("/static/",http.FileServer(http.Dir(os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "/src/github.com/krashcan/review/static"))))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil))
}

func ShowRatings(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
    t,err := template.ParseFiles(os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "/src/github.com/krashcan/review/template/index.tpl")
    if(err!=nil){
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    t.Execute(w,Movies)
}

func GetTitleAndYear(url string){
    resp,err := http.Get(url)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var movieData string
    if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        fmt.Println("statuscode",err)
    }
    z := html.NewTokenizer(resp.Body)
    for{
        tt := z.Next()

        if tt == html.ErrorToken{
            return
        }else if tt==html.StartTagToken{
            t:= z.Token()
            if t.Data=="h4"{
                tt = z.Next()
                tt = z.Next()
                tt = z.Next()
                t = z.Token()
                movieData = strings.TrimSpace(t.Data)               
                break
            }
        }
    }

    movie.Name = movieData[:len(movieData)-6]
    movie.Year = movieData[len(movieData)-5:len(movieData)-1]
    movie.Name = strings.Replace(movie.Name, " ", "+", -1)
    url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + movie.Name + "&y=" + movie.Year + "&plot=short&r=json"  
    req,err := http.Get(url)

    if err!=nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var x fileInfo
    jsonParser := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    if err := jsonParser.Decode(&x); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("parsing config file", err)
    }
    Movies = append(Movies,x)
    fmt.Println(x.Title,x.Year)     
}
```

This program ran perfectly for the first time. But after that it keeps on giving `net/http:TLS Handshake timeout` on random filenames. I am not sure what is causing this. What might be a possible solution? Also what exactly is this error?

EDIT 2: To solve the racing problem in concurrency, I used channels but now my program is very very slow compared to before. My updated main function :

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(flag.Args()[0])
    var queryNames []string
    for _, f := range files {
        queryNames= append(queryNames,url.QueryEscape(f.Name()))
    }
    //fmt.Println(os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "/src/github.com/krashcan/review/template/index.tpl")
    fmt.Println("Preparing data")
    ch := make(chan string)
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func(){
        for{
            name,more := <-ch
            if more{
                GetTitleAndYear("https://opensubtitles.co/search?q=" + name)
            }else{
                done <-true
            }
        }
    }()

    for i:=0;i<len(queryNames);i++{
        ch <- queryNames[i] 
    }
    <- done
    fmt.Println("Preparation DONE")
    http.HandleFunc("/",ShowRatings)
    http.Handle("/static/",http.StripPrefix("/static/",http.FileServer(http.Dir(os.Getenv("GOPATH") + "/src/github.com/krashcan/review/static"))))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil))
}
```

Please suggest me a way to have the same speed as before but also avoid racing around problems.

EDIT 1: I have added my complete program. There is no way to depict line no.s on stack overflow , I have used concurrency only in the main function. If you feel the need to advice me on my way of writing go programs, please do so, I am a beginner and I would love to do things right.

Comment: The only thing your first goroutine accomplishes, is causing a data race that possibly corrupts your slice. Once you remove all data races, please show a complete example.

Comment: I have added my complete program. And I totally think you are right. The first goroutine is the problam. Let me see how o fix it. Maybe I will just let it  complete the loop without using any goroutine there. It isnt taking much time anyways.

Comment: Yes you were right. It was because of the first goroutine. I am sorry, this was my first experience with concurrency. Thank you.

Comment: You can fix it by removing it. There nothing there that needs to be concurrent.

Comment: I removed it and I thought the problem was fixed but 1 out of 5 times it gives the TLS handshake error.

Comment: Your code still contains multiple race data races. Run your program with the race detector. This probably isn't causing the TLS error though. It may be an issue with the remote host, or the host could be rejecting your connections due to rate limiting or the limiting of concurrent connections.

Comment: I invite you to read this https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/

Comment: @JimB I used channels to try to fix the data racing but now the whole thing is slower. What is a better way to solve it? I have added my updated main code in the description.

Comment: @YandryPozo Thank you, I always forget to gofmt my code.

Comment: You've fixed the "problem" by removing the concurrency. You now have a single goroutine which synchronously gets each file one at a time. You could do the same thing much simpler with a single for loop. The timeouts were probably from your unbounded workers before. If you fix the race conditions you can add a few more workers and actually have some concurrency. (note, you should also `range` over the channel rather than use your `more` value).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `net/http` occurs when there is a large amount of http.Get() requests from client side. To avoid the `TLS handshake timeout error`,

```
t := &http.Transport{
            Dial: (&net.Dialer{
                    Timeout: 60 * time.Second,
                    KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            }).Dial,
            // We use ABSURDLY large keys, and should probably not.
            TLSHandshakeTimeout: 60 * time.Second,
    }
    c := &http.Client{
            Transport: t,
    }
    resp, err := c.Get("https://internal.lan/")
```

Found it [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/issues/241)